# How to prevent repeat in jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, slidetoggle

I have a simple jQuery function as

```
$('.button').click(function(){
   $("#target").slideToggle().load('http://page');
});
```

By `slideToggle` behavior, every click cause a slide, but the problem is that it will load `url` again too.

How can I limit the `load()` function to be performed only once, but `slideToggle()` on every click. In other words, how to prevent `load()` (only load, not the entire function) in the subsequent clicks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('.button')
    .on('click.loadPage', function() {
        $("#target").load('http://page');
        $(this).off("click.loadPage");
    })
    .on('click.slideToggle', function(){
        $("#target").slideToggle();
    });
```

and another way without global vars:

```
$('.button')
    .on('click', function() {
        if ( !$(this).data("loaded") ) {
            $("#target").load('http://page');
            $(this).data("loaded", true);
        }
        $("#target").slideToggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

Have a variable (global) which says whether it has been loaded or not. E.g:

```
var loaded = false;
$('.button').click(function(){
   if(!loaded){
      $('#target').load('http://page');
      loaded = true;
   }
   $("#target").slideToggle();
});
```

This will cause the slideToggle to occur on every click, but the page to load only the once. :)